# border-radius style doesn't work in android browser

Tags: android, browser, css

I created a website, which I intend to display in some mobile devices. The thing is that I have created several menu options as circles.

To achieve this effect I use border-radius in a style sheet, and -webkit-border-radius and-moz-border-radius too.

On the computer it looks well in the browsers I have (firefox and chrome), but when I move to the android browser, these circles are reset to be square divs. This occurs since the load of the page.

may I use other special style for android? Could I need something like the jQuery mobile?

In short I will put the code, but if anyone has gone something like, could share that information, please? thanks

Comment: I am having this exact same issue; I'm using a Galaxy S4 Active with an Android web browser; none of my border-radius CSS are working; they're all square. I've tried them in DIV's and in INPUT's; here's the CSS I'm using:


        #findA .bigButton 
        {
            width: 71%; height: 11%; margin: 3% auto; padding: 2% 0px;
            background-color: #521c0b; color: #FFFFFF;
            text-align: center;
   border: 3px solid #e3b21e;
            border-radius: 10px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
   background-clip: padding-box;   
        }

Answer (score 2):

See this post for the answer: [Galaxy S4 stock browser CSS3 border-radius support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17186158/galaxy-s4-stock-browser-css3-border-radius-support)

Just use the expanded border-left-radius, border-right-radius, etc as a workaround; it's a glitch in the new Android 4+ browser; a bug report has been submitted.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I am using this for gradient. And this works fine in most of the browsers.

```
`background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#B4DCFA), to(#FF0000));
-webkit-border-radius:11px;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);   
/* For WebKit (Safari, Google Chrome etc) */
/* For Mozilla/Gecko (Firefox etc) */
/* For Internet Explorer 5.5 - 7 */
/*-ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#B4DCFA,   endColorstr=#FF0000);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#B4DCFA), to(#FF0000));
`
```

Can you please post the code?

Comment: Does your example work in Android (not desktop Chrome, but mobile Android)? That is the browser that we both are having this problem.

Comment: I tried to put the code in this place, but I can't because of the limit of the characters. I will try to put it in a short way.

Comment: @HBlackorby: less than 50 reputation holders are not allowed to comment.

Comment: I didn't realize that; sorry @hima

Comment: Sorry for the delay,the important piece of the CSS code is this:`

.circulo{
 display:table;
 -moz-border-radius:50%;
 -ms-border-radius: 50%;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius:50%; 
 text-align:center;
  
}

.circulo p, #menuProyectos, #menuNosotros{
 display:table-cell;
 width:80%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 vertical-align:middle;
 text-align: center;
 color: #fff;
}

.submenus{
 color: #00438e;
}` Perhaps it's a conflict between styles, I don't know. Thanks for trying to help and sorry for the delay.

Comment: HBlackorby gives a solution in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17186158/galaxy-s4-stock-browser-css3-border-radius-support). I will try it and say if it works or not. Thanks for your help.