# border-radius not working in modern native Android browser

Tags: android, browser, css

I have a page that uses border-radius. It doesn't show up rounded in the native Android browser; it shows up with square corners. It shows up rounded in desktop Chrome, IE, FF, etc fine, but not in the native phone browser. Does anyone know if this is a problem with the browser itself, some additional CSS extension that I'm not using, etc?

Here's my CSS (in the demo):

```css
.bigButton2
{
    width: 320px; height: 200px; margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #521c0b; color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 3px solid #e3b21e;
    border-radius: 30px;    
   -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
   -moz-border-radius: 30px;
}
```

I've set up a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VJvQA/

I have tried with padding, without padding, with box-sizing, without box-sizing, and it just shows up as sharp corners. Any help or insight would be appreciated.

I realize that someone posted this already under ([border-radius style doesn't work in android browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944749/border-radius-style-doesnt-work-in-android-browser)), but he didn't provide any code, JSFiddle, and it was incorrectly answered with a general question without any real answer; I'd downvote it if I could, but I assumed prodviding an actual well-written question would be better. Thanks!

Comment: I've tested it in Android on a Galaxy S4 Active, so the most modern Android native browser out there.

Comment: Different browsers support different HTML5 and CSS3 features, it's just part of web development.

Comment: And I'd be fine with that, but according to http://caniuse.com/border-radius, it should work in Android Browsers, so I'm trying to see if it's a bug in this browser implemention, or if there's come conflict in my CSS or how my CSS is written that is causing the problem.

Comment: It's quite possible that website is wrong or referring to a different browser (I wouldn't be surprised if some networks/manufacturers replace the default browser along with other changes they make).

Comment: Your answer got me thinking if it's something specific to this actual phone model vs. Android browsers, and then I came across this (after searching on S/O for hours yesterday of course) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17186158/galaxy-s4-stock-browser-css3-border-radius-support

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Turns out, this issue is specific to the Android browser on the Galaxy S4 and S4 Active. It looks like they've broke support for the condensed border-radius property, but if you specify each corner individually, it works fine. I'm posting a bug report to Android. So, if you do this:

```
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
```

It works fine; if you just have border-radius: 10px; it gets ignored.

This was answered under this post:
[Galaxy S4 stock browser CSS3 border-radius support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17186158/galaxy-s4-stock-browser-css3-border-radius-support)
I'm just repeating it here. But I did test their solution, and it is working fine now on the Galaxy S4 Active as well.

Comment: Grats with your persistence, that's an odd inconsistency.

Comment: I'm running Cyanogenmod 11 on the S4 and not even this workaround seems to be working.

Comment: Well, doesn't work on Lenovo old models as well. Old devices should retire.

Comment: @sthonyau - this is from 2014. It was the modern device at the time. Your comment four years later is pretty useless.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, some browsers just don't support certain HTML5 and CSS3 properties. My advice and the general advice you'll find on the web is design your site so that it functions and looks nice across all browsers, and then go back and add CSS3 and HTML5 elements as an extra.

This is a well designed and laid out [table showing HTML5 and CSS3 support across browsers](http://fmbip.com/litmus/), it doesn't, however, show the support for mobile browsers.

[This link](http://mobilehtml5.org), shows support for mobile devices.

**EDIT 2019-11-07**

With HTML5 and CSS3 widely supported across all modern browsers dating back several years, plus many JavaScript plugins designed to provide polyfills should you need to support much older browsers, this question and my original answer are both severely outdated.

On that note, it's pretty amazing how far we've come in just 5 or so years :)

New answer: HTML5 and CSS3 all the things!

Comment: According to your own link (the second one), Android browsers should support rounded corners, so I'm back to wondering if it's something I'm specifically doing in that CSS that is breaking it.

Comment: Yea that is really strange. I've never come across an issue with border radius in any browser. But your code looks completely fine.

Comment: If it's a button, I'm assuming you have a :hover psuedo? If you do, try setting the border radius on that too. Since its lower in the cascade it might be overriding the border radius to the default which is none. Just a shot in the dark @HBlackorby

Comment: No :hover, but I read the answer under another post; I was searching yesterday for "Android" of course, not "Galaxy S4". It's a very weird glitch to find in a modern phone.

Answer (score 0):

I see this on another topic.

and to work on mobile just do this:

```
border-collapse: separate;
```

with border-radius (im also try border-radius separated)

```
border-top-left-radius: 20px;
border-top-right-radius: 20px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
border-collapse: separate;
```

Tell me if works. Cya

Comment: This question was specifically about the stock Android web browser app that came shipped with Galaxy S4 (and other phones around that time). It's been since fixed in Galaxy stopped shipping with stock Android browsers, so it's no longer a concern on any modern Galaxy phone. Also, I'm pretty sure future versions of the Android web browser fixed this issue.

Comment: oh, sorry, didnt see this. Any mod may delete my comment if its not necessary. Sorry for that.

Answer (score -1):

I think your code is not wrong, it can not display on tablet devices by do. background border should have to fix this error you should delete the lines

```css
background-color: #521c0b; 
color: #FFFFFF;
```

or deleting row

```css
border: 3px solid red
```

I think this is not a bug and I've met a lot of work as above :) 
p / s: sorry my english is not very good

Comment: The answer above about splitting the CSS out into individual properties fixes the issue. There's nothing wrong with the background-color or regular border CSS.