# Bug with css semicircle in android native browser

Tags: html, css, android-browser

I want to dry semicircle by css. In all other browsers it works good, but in Android native browser it looks like this:

https://pp.vk.me/c540102/c617716/v617716567/1a373/HP4yReINnwg.jpg

```
div {
    width: 56px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 56px 56px 0px 0px;
    background: green;
    background: #7ed035;
}
```

This is code in jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/ewz7us6r/1/

Comment: hey did the answer help?

Answer (score 1):

try declaring them independantly i.e;

```
border-top-left-radius: 56px;
border-top-right-radius: 56px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
```

as it might be related to this [border-radius not working in modern native Android browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973394/border-radius-not-working-in-modern-native-android-browser)