# CSS border radius not working into Android webview

Tags: android, html, android-webview, css

I have a Android app based on a Webview.

The major part of the app is designed using JS, HTML and CSS. It's also based on Bootstrap.

Globally, the app is working fine. However the issue which concerns me today is: a button is not correctly displayed but the problem has been seen only on one smartphone model today (Alcatel TCT Orange Hiro under Android 4.2.2).

The button is designed with circles drawn by CSS. With the smartphone above the circles are displayed as squares as if the Webview was not understanding neither border-radius nor -webkit-border-radius CSS commands.

The HTML:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="text-center">
            <div id="button_border" class="button_play">                    
                <div id="button_content" class="button_play">
                    <div id="button_content_play" class="pictogramme">&#9654;</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Edit: The CSS is loaded within the HTML by:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
```

For this, the CSS contains:

```
/*position and global appearance of the button's outer portion. The circle is drawn by using border-radius: 50% */
#button_border {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 27%;
    left: 20%;
    width: 55%;
    z-index: 7;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
/*Specific design for the play button's outer portion*/
#button_border.button_play {
    background-color: #01b169;
    border: solid .5em #3c3e43;
}
/*Button colors change when touched*/
#button_border.button_play:focus, 
#button_border.button_play:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: white;
}

/*Position and global appearance of the button's body portion. The circle is drawn by using border-radius: 50% */
#button_content {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 8;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
#button_content.button_play {
    background-color: white;
    color: #01b169;
    border: solid .1em #01b169;
}
/*Body button colors change when touched*/
#button_content.button_play:focus, 
#button_content.button_play:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: #01b169;
}
/*Play symbol has to be centered in the button*/
#button_content_play {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Edit: the java code to load the web view is as follows: in the onCreate() method from my MainActivity, I have:

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

    // Add HTML views to the webviews
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/home.html");

    /**
     * Allow access from file URL (for AJAX request and
     * internationalization)
     */
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
        Class<?> clazz = webView.getSettings().getClass();
        Method method;
        try {
            method = clazz.getMethod("setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs",
                    boolean.class);
            if (method != null) {
                method.invoke(webView.getSettings(), true);
            }
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Does someone know how I can resolve this issue?

Note: other difficulty I get is that I'm not able to reproduce the issue myself because I don't own this specific device and the simulator with Android 4.2.2 shows the button as expected.

Thanks by advance to save my life

Comment: show me your code how to load `css` into `webview`?

Comment: I edited my question adding both java code loading the web view and html code linking the CSS file

Answer (score 0):

Please Replace This css.....

```
#button_content {

     position: absolute;
     z-index: 8;

     border-radius: 50px;
    -o-border-radius topleft: 50px;  
    -o-border-radius topright: 50px;
    -o-border-radius bottomleft: 50px;
    -o-border-radius bottomright: 50px;

    -webkit-border-radius topleft: 50px;  
    -webkit-border-radius topright: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius bottomleft: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius bottomright: 50px;


}
```

Comment: I don't well understand… In what the fact to separate the border-radius command is better? Furthermore replace % by px causes square with rounded corners to be drawn instead of a circle as I wish. Another question about your response is why use -o prefix on Android? It's for Opera browser, isn't it? The Android webview engine is based on Webkit if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I'm sorry but it would seem that exploding the condensed border-radius property could solve the issue due to strange CSS behaviors in modern Android browsers. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17186158/galaxy-s4-stock-browser-css3-border-radius-support

Comment: I'm going to see from the user getting this issue to confirm to me if it's solve thanks to your advice. I'll keep you inform.

Comment: I just got back from the user and exploding the condensed border-radius property does not solve the issue. Unfortunately, nothing is changed. I'm looking for any other suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

For me it seems to work if not all the values are equal. So this fails:

```
border-top-left-radius: 50px;
border-top-right-radius: 50px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
```

But the following works:

```
border-top-left-radius: 50px;
border-top-right-radius: 50px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 49.99999px;
```

Don't add too many decimals, because 49.999999px doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It occurs when the rounded element also has a background, that leaks through rounded corners.

This worked for me:

```
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
-moz-background-clip: padding-box;
background-clip: padding-box;
```