# How do I solve JQuery Mobile `ui-corner-all` Corners

Tags: android, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am currently using JQuery Mobile 1.4.0 for a PhoneGap Application but I have this problem of corners not forming properly (they are flat instead of curving). When am using JQuery Mobile 1.3.2, it does not have this problem. I have tried downgrading/upgrading the Jquery.js library but am still to find a solution, I have even created my own theme and still no solution. Below is a screenshot of what am talking about.

Note:
- All libraries are attached properly
- It works well on Firefox and chrome desktop browser
- I am testing on Android 4.2.1

[image: JQuery Mobile Corners]

Thanks, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Add `ui-corner-all` to popup div and anchor tag. You can use this class anywhere.

Comment: I am using it. The problem is that it doesn't work properly

Comment: do you have border radius in the css rule of .ui-corner-all?

Comment: In the .CSS file of the theme?

Answer (score 0):

On .ui-corner-all, try adding this...

```
.ui-corner-all{
     border-top-left-radius: .3125em;
     border-top-right-radius: .3125em;
     border-bottom-left-radius: .3125em;
     border-bottom-right-radius: .3125em;
}
```

I found this post: [Galaxy S4 stock browser CSS3 border-radius support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17186158/galaxy-s4-stock-browser-css3-border-radius-support)